# Nuxt.js: middleware для раздела на сайте

Tags: nuxt.js, vue-router

На сайте есть набор однотипных разделов, с структурой вроде `sections/{type}/page/inside`.
Структура разделов одинаковая, может использоваться один набор компонентов, нужно только данные разные подставить.
Список разделов нефиксированный, берётся из базы.

Создаю компоненты вроде `pages/sections/_type/page/inside.vue`, всё роутится, как надо.

Но на каждой внутренней странице нужно убедиться, что указанный `{type}` вообще существует и к нему есть доступ.
А также подгрузить связанные с ним данные.
Хотелось бы, ясное дело, не копипастить этот код в каждый компонент.
Видимо, нужно использовать middleware.

- Можно ли указать middleware для папки-в роуте (`sections/_type`). Или придётся прописывать для каждой вложенной страницы?
- Как лучше прокинуть загруженные в middleware данные в компонент страницы?
  Сохранить в store в свойстве вроде "currentType"?
  Но в store, как я понимаю, состояние приложения "вообще", а не конкретного запроса.

Answer (score 0):

По вопросу "как задать middleware для всех страниц внутри каталога".
В соответствии с этим: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52407433/how-to-add-middleware-to-a-group-of-routes-in-nuxt/52408709
нужно создать рядом с каталогом `_type` файл `_type.vue` и там прописать базовый компонент с нужными свойствами.

Что это за магия и где в документации она описана не знаю, но работает.